# Which python template language allows filling in variables from a dictionary?

Tags: python, jinja2, template-engine, mako

I want to generate a configuration file for some external software package. The configuration file requires some sensitive information like AWS access keys and passwords etc. I want to make these configuration files public on github but obviously I don't want to hardcode and expose these credentials.

The credentials also have to show up in the right place in the config file so I can't just "cat" them on to the end.

I figured that using a tempting language like jinja2,mako, django etc would be a good solution. Then I can just put the the templates online and require the user to make a new file with credentials and run a script (that I provide) to render the template. A template engine would also enable other more sophisticated editing (I think).

Can someone recommend a particular template engine that would make this easy? I imagine something where you make a template and then render it by providing a dictionary containing the variables to assign. Maybe they all do this. I don't know.

To be a little more specific I would like something that does something like this

```
Template("Hello {{name}}, you are #{{num}}").render({"name":"Joe","num":1})
```

All the templates that I see look like this

```
Template("Hello {{name}}, you are #{{num}}").render(name="Joe", num=1)
```

That makes it difficult to write a general program which reads a parameter file of key value pairs and hands them to a template to render. For example, it might require using "eval" which is awkward.

Comment: You could always unpack your dictionary into keywords in the function call with `.render(**mydict)`

Comment: try the Mako template language

Comment: Blckknght, I don't understand. Can you give an example? I'd rather not have to change the code when someone adds another key-value pair. For example, someone might want to change my template and add a line like "install XXX user={{XXX_user}} password= {XXX_password}}"

Comment: I want this to work by just adding XXX_user and XXX_password to the other private file. I'd rather not have to have them modify the script which does this substitution.

Comment: This shouldn't be labeled an opinion-based question. I asked for a specific package that could fill out a template from a dictionary. The answer, apparently, was that they all do that if you use the ** syntax. Beyond that, I'm not asking for opinions on which template engine is best. So please take off of hold. It's a valid and educational question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your templating language only allows `render(a=foo, b=bar)`, you can work around it like so: `d = {"a": foo, "b": bar}; render(**d)` -- no need for eval.

For more info, read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Hmm. I did not know that about Python. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with any templating system. If your parameters are in a dictionary but the template API requires keywords, use [argument unpacking syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
my_template.render(**my_parameter_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather opinion based, but I use jinja2 in combination with YAML.

Jinja2 is very flexible and allows looping, escaping etc.

YAML is easy to edit, can be converted to python dictionary and values of this Python dictionary can be used as base for rendering your templates.

I was pleased to find SaltStack solution using as default just these two - Jinja2 and YAML. Probably for good reasons.